# Does anyone know a tool for Git similar to SVN Time-Lapse View

Tags: svn, git

SVN Time-Lapse View is a cross-platform viewer that downloads all revisions of a file and lets you scroll through them by dragging a slider. As you scroll, you are shown a visual diff of the current revision and the previous revision. Thus you can see how a file evolved, and you can easily find the revision at which lines appeared, disappeared, or changed.

http://code.google.com/p/svn-time-lapse-view/

Comment: If there's a Git Java library, you can modify SVN Time Lapse View to use it.

Comment: The screenshot does not exist anymore, but there's a [video](https://www.perforce.com/resources/tutorials/using-time-lapse-view-2) now.

Answer (score 4):

From the command line, I suggest one way:

```
git whatchanged -p pathToACertainFile
```

Which will show all the full diffs that have occurred to that file, and which sha hash they were done at (from latest to earliest).  Best if you have your terminal set up to show stuff colorized.

Comment: This seems to be the same as `git log -p pathToACertainFile`

Comment: As to the color issue, you could add `--color=always`

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite a slider, but the Git bundle for TextMate lets you browse revisions for a single file via a dropdown menu. It highlights changes for the current revision, and also names the person who last edited a line, `svn blame`-style. There are also keyboard shortcuts for navigation to previous/next revisions.

<del>http://blog.macromates.com/2008/git-bundle/</del>

Update 2014-05-10: Now available on GitHub: https://github.com/textmate/git.tmbundle

Answer (score 3):

I created git-time-lapse-view based on svn-time-lapse-view here:

https://github.com/JonathanAquino/git-time-lapse-view

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may want to spend some time exploring `git log` command and `gitk` (`gitk` works with many of the same options as `git log`).

Comment: Used gitk for years and never knew this. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a mac, you might want to try [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/)

As quoted from the site:

> GitX is a git GUI specifically for Mac
>   OS X. It currently features a history
>   viewer much like gitk and a commit GUI
>   like git gui. But then in silky smooth
>   OS X style!
>
> Features:
>
> - Detailed history viewer
> - Nice commit GUI, allowing per-commit    staging
> - Fast Nice Aqua interface
> - Paste commits to gist.github.com
> - Explore tree of any revision
> - QuickLook integration

May not do completely what you want but the history viewer should help.

Answer (score 1):

Recently two new projects popped up:

- [scm-time-lapse-view](https://github.com/vlovich/scm-time-lapse-view) (fork of svn-time-lapse-view, Java)
- [git-time-lapse](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3849) (Vim script)

Unfortunately neither of them worked for me on a local repository :-(