# tig blame view: How to come back (child commit) after loading parent commit

Tags: git-blame, tig

In a blame view, I use ','  to load blame for the parent commit. How to come back to the child?

Answer (score 8):

You can come back to the child with `<`, i.e. `shift` + `,`

Answer (score 6):

How I use TIG blame view:

- Step backwards in time to the commit of a given line (B key)
- Step backwards to the parent commit of a given line (, key).
- Stepping forwards can be done by going to the main view (m key), selecting a more recent revision, and entering blame view again (B key).

It does not preserve the viewing location when stepping to a parent commit (it seems to when using the line's commit).

(From my answer elsewhere https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301595/331858)

Answer (score 3):

Example usage pattern:

Open [tig](https://jonas.github.io/tig/) in your git repository's folder:

```
cd your/repo
tig
```

---

1. Use up / down cursor keys - to select the revision you want to start from
2. <kbd>t</kbd> - enter tree view
3. up / down / <kbd>enter</kbd> to find the file you want
4. <kbd>b</kbd> to open blame view
5. up / down - to move up and down the lines in the file
6. View full patch for selected line:

   - <kbd>enter</kbd> to view the last patch for that line
   - <kbd>q</kbd> to close the patch view
7. To view older versions:

   - <kbd>,</kbd> - to show the blame of the file from **before** this patch
   - <kbd><</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>shift+,</kbd>) to step back out to more recent versions of the file

---

You can jump straight to a file with:

```
tig blame filename
```